# Create a cron job to run redis every 30 minutes if it is not running

Tags: cron, redis

I want to create a cron job that will run redis every 30 minutes if it is not already running, but I don't know what I should do.

I know that the beginning should look like this `*/30 * * * */<some path to redis-server file>`.

I want to create this cron job because its get a little tedious running redis via `./redis-server` every time it crashes.

I figured out it was crashing because my memory usage was a bit over the limit.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Redis + Monit: https://gist.github.com/cyx/3690597

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Redis shouldn't be crashing. I'd focus on that first. Is it running out of RAM?
2. Use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) or [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/), or run Redis through something like [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: I am sort of familiar with supervisor as I am using it to run celery.  How would I run redis with this method?  Would I let the command=./<path>/redis-stable?

Comment: Yeah use supervisor or runit to keep it going.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1495/

Answer (score 1):

The answer that focusing on why it's crashing is the right thing to do.  For future reference if someone is looking for a way to cron a check for an app running and start it if it's not, I've always done so with a bash script.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if httpd is running
if pgrep "httpd" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    /etc/init.d/httpd start
fi
```

Then you can cron the bash script even every minute.  That's the simple version.  I'd also suggest logging the restarts to a script to help you track down when your application is crashing so you can review logs.